# Div Floats and Overflow in relation to size of the browser

Tags: css

I have a website built with divs floated to various parts of the pages to create the look I want. My problem is, when I make my browser smaller the floats all cram to the left side instead of holding their positions and simply giving a scroll bar.

All I want is for my pages to hold their form when the browser is not maximized.

Comment: please give the link on your site or html / css code

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you put a **min-width** on the div wrapping all your floating divs.
Than all your div will be floating as normally, but when the browser will be smaller you will have a scroll bar.

Comment: I'll try it. 
Just to be clear, though: You mean encase all of my divs in 1 div with a min-width, right?

Comment: Exactly, told me if there's any problem :)

Comment: Used the min-width suggestion and everything is looking good. Thanks for the quick response and the help. Isn't it funny how simple a solution seems after someone else has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah the code would really help, but a solution (I think) would be to wrap all your floated divs in a div that has a defined width.

Comment: Would it be more helpful/less prone to error if I just individually re-positioned my divs instead of relying on floats? 
I know it will take me a while to correct my error, but I just want to use the method that will be biggest benefit to my code.

Comment: really depends of your code ... and what you are trying to do ... maybe give us a fiddle or a part of your code